Using viewshed to determine how much of wind turbine can be seen in ArcMap
I would like to know how much I can still see of a wind turbine 10 km (point shapefile) away from my observer point (point shapefile). The viewshed analysis only tells me whether I can see the wind turbine or not, but not how much of it. I really like to know whether I can still see 50 meters or only 10 meters of the tip of the turbine from my observer point.
Which ArcGIS tool could help me?
We have ArcMap 10.8 with Spatial Analyst (no 3D Analyst) and I use a digital surface model 2x2 meters of the region in question.

You could run the viewshed for every 5 to 10 m between total height and hub height and compare that data. Or you could use special visualization software.

In QGIS there is the GDAL tool viewshed, that you also can run in batch mode.
As input it requires your DSM Raster and a pointlayer (observer and target).
So you could set different values for the target hight and see the respective result.

If you wish to also ask about doing this in QGIS then please do that in a separate question so that you can tell us what you’ve tried with that software.

I wonder how well those algorithms deal with trees, even when there is DSM to use.

Hi, thanks Erik. I had the same idea, but would be kind of "unclean".

Hi nepluisse, I currently trying the QGIS viewshed tool. I created a new question - as requested.

This is a highly relevant piece of work if you don't already cite it?
